# Help me to solve a problem with rectangles. I cannot resize rectangles and save proportions.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have two rectangles with different sizes. I need to resize second rectangle to fit proportions of a first one.

First rectangle :

- w1:350
- h1:150
- S1:150*350=52500
- propotion1:350/150=2,333

Second rectangle:

- w2:500
- h2:430
- S2:500*430=215000
- propotion2:500/430=1,16

i need to find **w3** and **h3** of third rectangle so **S2=S3** and proportions **w1/h1=w3/h3** should be same (2,3 like for a first rectangle).

But i cannot get it how to do this.

Result of equations should be something near
w3=730
h3=300 but this is quess actually. How to find those **w3** and **h3**?

Calculator gives me a numbers but still i dont get it. How he actually found it:

[image]

Comment: even in your case given w/h  for first and second rectangle are not the same. w1/h1 not equal to w2/h2 as stated in question. then how can we find w3/h3

Comment: w3/h3 should be 2,3 like a proportion1.

Comment: what is w2/h2 then ? you told w1/h1 = w2/h2 ?

Comment: Since $S1\ne S2$, you won't be able to find arrive at $S1=S2=S3$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen question is edited. This is mistake. As result i need third rectangle with same S3 as in S2 and w1/h1=w3/h3

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam Question is edited. And if you mean that we cannot solve this equation then should exists at least agoritm how to find it with min efforts\steps.

Comment: Ya your calculator answer is what I have given in my answer .multiple 101.83 with 7 and 3 to get your calcutor answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you gave $w_{1}/h_{1} = 7/3= w_{3}/h_{3} $

$S_{2} = S_{3} = 215000 $

So
$S_{3} = w_{3} * h_{3} $

as ratio is 7/3 , so some factor mutiplied by 7 is w3 and same factor multiplied by 3 is h3 . let that factor be x

$215000 = 7x * 3x $

$x^2 = 10238.09 $

$ x = 101.183 $

so

$w_{3} = 7*x = 708.28 $

$h_{3} = 3*x = 303.549 $

And your guess is wrong as it is not equal to 215000. your guess gives answer 219000.

> As you stated in comments for program, procedure to find w3 and h3 is
>   as follows
>
> step1 : find 350/150 = 2.3333
>
> step2 : divide  215000 by 2.333
>
> step3 : find square root of the value in step 2 . which is the factor
>   x = 303.57
>
> step4 : w3 = 2.333 * 303.57 , h3 = 303.57
>
> apply above in a program to get the desired w3 and h3

Comment: Thanks for answer. Exact w3 and h3 is not required. Small  
infelicity is allowed. But i cannot still get it how to write exact formula for w3=... and h3=... :(

Comment: i have updated the answer .

Comment: unfortunately still have a problem with this. I am trying to use this to develop PC software. Cannot get how to find those "magic" numbers "7","3" PC just cannot get it that 2.3 is equals to 7/3.  Is it possible to operate only with those variables w1,h1,w2,h2,w3,h3 S1,S2,S3 and solve this issue?

Comment: so your problem is how software will be able to find the ratio as  7/3 right.so no problem . assume numbers as 2.333x and x as 7/3 is 2.3333. and do 215000 = 2.333x * x and find x.

Comment: 7/3 is nothing but answer of 350/150 . to software feed in 350 ,150 and divide it , then do as this value 215000/( value got in division) , then take square root . this will give x . now x = 303.549 , so w3 = 2.333x = 708.28 and h3 = x = 303.549 . these steps can be directly done with ease in a program

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. You're the hero of the day

Comment: Thank you very much. I am also a programmer, so was able to understand your problem.If the answer is satisfactory you can accept it by clicking tick mark against the answer .

Answer (score 1):

Given a desired area, $S3,$ and a desired proportion $p=\frac {w3}{h3}$, we have $h3=p*w3, S3=w3*h3=p*(w3)^2$ so $w3=\sqrt{\frac {S3}p}, h3=\sqrt{p*S3}$  You need to make sure you are using floating point numbers instead of integers, or $p$ will get truncated to an integer.